# Doubt about the definition of fine moduli space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, moduli-space, algebraic-stacks

I’m studying [“Introduction to differentiable stacks”](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Eginot/papers/DiffStacksIGG2013.pdf) (Grégory Ginot) and I don’t understand a technicality in the (somewhat informal) definition of fine moduli space given at page 12.

Basically if we want to classify a certain class of algebro-geometric objects $\mathcal{G}$ up to isomorphism, a fine moduli space is a space $M$ whose points are in 1 to 1 correspondence with isomorphism classes of $\mathcal{G}$, and a map $\mathscr{U}\to M$ such that the fiber of $m$ is in the isomorphism class represented by $m$. This map $\mathscr{U}\to M$ should also be universal in the sense that any other family $\mathscr{F}\to N$ should be the *“pullback of the universal family through an unique arrow $f:N\to M$”*.

My source says that the phrase in italics means that the following diagram is cartesian:
$\hspace{4 cm}$[image]

What is the top arrow? Is it unique or are we requiring that $f$ is the unique arrow such that a top arrow that makes the diagram cartesian exists?

Comment: I understand that the top arrow must make the diagram cartesian, but I don’t understand what is the top arrow...

Comment: I know what is a pullback. Are you suggesting that the top arrow is the composition of the isomorphism $\mathscr{F}\cong \mathscr{U}\times_M N$ with the standard map $\mathscr{U}\times_M N \to \mathscr{U}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is as follows.  For any $F→N$ there is a unique arrow $f$ such that there is an isomorphism $F→N ⨯_M U$ over $N$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Each fiber of $\mathscr U \to M$ is the object which is represented by its base point $m \in M$. In the same way, the family $\mathscr F \to N$ associates to points $n \in N$ its fiber, and in that way an element $\mathscr F_n$ of $\mathcal G$. Now the map $\mathscr F \to \mathscr U$ identifies $\mathscr F_n$ with $\mathscr U_m$, where $f(n) = m$.

I think an example can be helpful. As you now, a point $[v]$ in projective space $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb C}$ represents a line $\mathbb Cv \subset \mathbb C^{n+1}$. Taking all those lines together, we obtain a complex¹ line bundle
$$L = \{([v], w) : w \in \mathbb C v\} \subset \mathbb P^{n} \times \mathbb C^{n+1}.$$
As it turns out, $\mathbb P^n$ actually is a fine moduli space for this situation. So given any manifold $X$, together with a complex line subbundle
$$L' \subset X \times \mathbb C^{n+1},$$
there is a unique map
$$X \to \mathbb P^n$$
which sends $x \in X$ to the point $[L'_x] \in \mathbb P^{n}$. This map extends to a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
L' @>>> L \\
@Vi'VV @ViVV\\
X \times \mathbb C^{n+1} @>f\times \operatorname{id}>> \mathbb P^n \times \mathbb C^{n+1}\\
@V\operatorname{pr}_XVV @V\operatorname{pr}_{\mathbb P^n}VV\\\
X @>>> \mathbb P^n
\end{CD}$$
where $i'$ and $i$ are the given inclusions.

---

¹ I guess all of this can also be done for real projective space, but I'm just more comfortable with complex projective space.